# Can I solve a 4th order polynomial in R?

Tags: r, equation-solving

I wish to predict leaf temperature (TL) from other variables. The energy balance equation I have developed, simplified, is

A = B*TL^4 + C*TL + D

Is there any way to solve for TL so I have an equation of the form "TL=...", preferably using an R-based package?

Comment: Is CTL a separate variable, or is that C times (TL)? (Maybe just use single letters for variable terms, like small _x_ for leaf temperature, to make the equation less confusing.)

Comment: Yes, it would be better expressed as A=Bx^4 + Cx + D

Comment: If you are looking for an analytic solution for a quartic function: See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function for the solution.  For a numerical solution use the `nls()` function in R